# AutoGPT install: AttributeError: 'TTSHandler' object has no attribute 'level'

Tags: python, attributeerror, python-logging, autogpt

I am trying to install autogpt on my Mac (python 3.10, pip) and get this "AttributeError" problem, here is the terminal output. I don't know much about Python, please help, many thanks!

```
2023-08-30 16:53:35,439 WARNING  You are running on `master` branch - this is not a supported branch.
2023-08-30 16:53:36,256 INFO  Welcome to Auto-GPT!  run with '--help' for more information.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    autogpt.app.cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1666, in invoke
    rv = super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/app/cli.py", line 121, in main
    run_auto_gpt(
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/app/main.py", line 152, in run_auto_gpt
    ai_config = construct_main_ai_config(
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/app/main.py", line 504, in construct_main_ai_config
    ai_config = interactive_ai_config_setup(config)
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/app/setup.py", line 38, in interactive_ai_config_setup
    user_friendly_output(
  File "/Users/sharron.x/Auto-GPT/autogpt/logs/helpers.py", line 29, in user_friendly_output
    logger.log(level, message, extra={"title": title, "title_color": title_color})
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1547, in log
    self._log(level, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1624, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1634, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1695, in callHandlers
    if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
AttributeError: 'TTSHandler' object has no attribute 'level'
```

I have already run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and googled the relevant content and it seems to be related to some functions that are not inherited in TTSHandler. I don’t know which environment modules are not installed and configured properly. I haven’t learned much about Python, so please help me~